# How to append a initializer_list returned from a function to another vector?

Tags: c++

I would like to append a `initializer_list` of objects returned from a function to another `vector`, ideally as a 1 liner like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> integers(0);
    integers.reserve(8);
    integers.insert(integers.end(), generate_4_ints()); // vector size is now 4
    integers.insert(integers.end(), generate_4_ints()); // vector size is now 8
}

std::initializer_list<int> generate_4_ints()
{
    int first = 1, second = 2, third = 3, fourth = 4;
    return {first, second, third, fourth};
}
```

The only problem with the code above is that the values returned from `generate_4_ints()` lose their assigned value and instead return garbage, as if no copies were returned. I assume this is some peculiar behavior to do with `initializer_list`.

Comment: Your C++ compiler should've showed you a warning message that explains what the problem is. gcc certainly did. So, if your compiler did not issue any messages, it's time to get a better compiler. If your compiler ***did*** issue a warning message, then this demonstrates why diagnostic messages from a C++ compiler should not be ignored, even if the compiler produces an executable. Did your compiler issue ***any*** diagnostic message for the shown code?

Comment: Your question says "vector returned from function" but your code is returning an `initializer_list`. Which one is it?

Comment: I can not see vector begin returned from the function.

Comment: @cigien I don't care which one it is, the point is just to append the integers to `integers`. The reason why I returned an `initializer_list` is simply to show the result that I'm looking for and because it kind of worked but not quite.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Unfortunately MSVC 19.26.28806 did not output any warnings

Comment: gcc's diagnostic message would've informed you what the problem is: `warning: returning temporary ‘initializer_list’ does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array`

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't care which one is returned, that's additional information you can add to the question. But the question still needs to be consistent, and besides, you only get the weird behavior you're describing if you return an `initializer_list`.

Comment: I do not get any warning with clang either. You should treat `initializer_list`s as if it always had a reference `&` next to it. You should not store it nor return it.

Comment: `generate_4_ints` should return `std::vector<int>`.